# GridView of specified apps in a Dialog in Android

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-dialog

Can Any One Please suggest code to display specified app icons in grid manner (say 3*3) in a dialog in android.? ( On clicking the app icon the respective app should be opened )

-Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `DialogFragment` class. Within the `onCreateDialog` method you can create an `AlertDialog` and set its `View` to your custom view (in this case a `GridView`). Then in your `Activity` you can make an instance of your `DialogFragment` and call the `show` method on it.